# How to do parametrized query using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create a parametrized query, to compare price.

This is the query that I use, the problem is that it does not show me to anything or sometime it show

> 'Must declare the scalar variable "@prc1". .

Is my query right ?

Also is my parametrized code right ?

What I have tried:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

    con.Open();

    try
    {
        string price1 = Convert.ToString(Session[price1]);

        String q = "SELECT * FROM legacy WHERE [price] >= @prc1";

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(q, con);

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(@prc1, price1);

        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = q;
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you dont need to encode your query (q) statement in quotes?

Comment: String q = "SELECT * FROM legacy WHERE [price] >= @prc1 "; This is actual code. now tell me what is wrong with its.

Comment: It is unlikely that the issue is within the query itself, that was just an obvious syntax error in the question. What value is in Session[price1] when the page loads? What if that is null?

Comment: @naviolegacy, `SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = q;` is the problem. It know nothing about the parameter

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? you created a command object and then set value for its variable again you set sqldatasource command property with string..?? i think you need only :

SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = q;
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("prc1",price1);
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();

Comment: Your "code" has at least 2 copy/paste mistakes, so you could not have executed it to get this error. Next time, please post the code as you have executed it.

Answer (score 0):

the `SqlDataSource1` know nothing about the parameter in the query.

[SqlDataSource.SelectParameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the parameters collection that contains the parameters that are
>   used by the SelectCommand property from the SqlDataSourceView object
>   that is associated with the SqlDataSource control.

```
var price1 = Convert.ToString(Session[price1]);

var q = "SELECT * FROM legacy WHERE [price] >= @prc1";

SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = q;
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("prc1", price1);
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```